# jQuery Slide effect slides div separately

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a simple slide effect but it is not working the way I want, please help me out. if anyone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.

1. what I want to do is have the div slide up as one div not 2 div. when you click on a button the div slides down/up before the arrow head, I would like both the arrow head and the div to slide up/down.
2. when the user clicks on a button the other open div slides up before the clicked button div slides down.

here is an example of my work.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dSCxJ/

```
<div id="main_content">

              <ul class="categories_list">

                  <li class="animated">
                     <a href="#propsal_templates" class="main_buttons">
                          <span class="category_list_titles">
                              <table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td height="150" align="center" valign="middle">Proposal Templates</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                          </span>
                      </a>
                  </li>

                  <li class="animated">
                     <a href="#2" class="main_buttons">
                          <span class="category_list_titles">
                              <table width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                  <td height="150" align="center" valign="middle">Site Lists</td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                          </span>
                      </a>
                  </li>

              </ul>

              <div id="propsal_templates" class="document_wrapper" style="display:none;">
                      <div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border1"></div>
                      <div class="chat-bubble-arrow1"></div>
                          <table width="950" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="316" valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon powerpoint_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td width="316" valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon pdf_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td width="310" valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon excel_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="middle">
                              <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon word_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon powerpoint_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon powerpoint_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="middle">
                              <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon word_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon powerpoint_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle">

                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                      </div>

              <div id="2" class="document_wrapper" style="display:none;">
                      <div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border2"></div>
                      <div class="chat-bubble-arrow2"></div>
                          <table width="950" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                            <tr>
                              <td width="316" valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon powerpoint_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td width="316" valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon pdf_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td width="310" valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon excel_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="middle">
                              <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon word_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon powerpoint_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle">
                                <a href="test.docx">
                                    <span class="icon pdf_icon"></span>
                                    <span class="doc_name">General</span>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                      </div>
```

```
//centers categories names
jQuery.fn.center = function(){
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top","50%");
    this.css("left","50%");
    this.css("margin-top","-"+(this.height()/2)+"px");
    this.css("margin-left","-"+(this.width()/2)+"px");
    return this;
}
$(".category_list_titles").center();

//button action
$('ul.categories_list li a.main_buttons').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var div = $(this).attr("href");
    //alert(div);

    if($(this).hasClass('selected_button'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected_button');
        //$(''+div+'').fadeOut();
        $(''+div+'').slideUp(
            { 
                duration: 500, 
                easing: 'easeInQuad',
            }
        );
    }
    else
    {
      $('ul.categories_list li a.main_buttons').each(function(i) {
          $('ul.categories_list li a.main_buttons').removeClass('selected_button');
          //$('.document_wrapper').css('display', 'none');
          $('.document_wrapper').slideUp(
            { 
                duration: 500, 
                easing: 'easeInQuad',
            }
          );
      });

      $(this).addClass('selected_button');
      //$(''+div+'').fadeIn();
      $(''+div+'').slideDown(
        { 
            duration: 500, 
            easing: 'easeInQuad',
        }
      );
    }   
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i am not sure if this is what you asking, you want to slideup and, when slideup completes, slideup arrow as a continuous animation? if this is it check http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/ , u can use complete method. And when your slideup completes do another slideup on the arrow div

Comment: If you're animating multiple items then then `slideUp/Down` seem to animate at the same time. To stop that you either need to animate just one element and use the callback on `slideUp`, or use a `.done()` to make sure all animations have finished.

I've updated your jsFiddle for the animations, but not the arrows. http://jsfiddle.net/dSCxJ/1/

Comment: You could work around the arrow problem by using the blind effect in jQuery, but it doesn't look as nice and you get some animation issues due to the CSS. See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dSCxJ/2/

Comment: thx Klors, i forgot about the jquery when/done functions.

Comment: i tried the blind effect before but like you said i got the issue of the div showing up in weird places before it slide down.

Comment: For #2 - you need to have the 2nd animation run after the first one is complete.  In the slideUp options, set a 'complete' function that will run the slideDown after slideUp is finished

Answer (score 0):

as an option, you can create your own small functions (or jquery plugins) for slideup and slidedown, which use jquery animation changing opacity and position, this would solve arrow problem. slideup may have a function argument that would be executed in the end of animation, so that you could use subsequent animations

```
$.fn.mySlideDown = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).stop(true,true)
           .css({"opacity": 0, "top":"-225px"}).show()
           .animate({ "opacity":1,"top":"-25px"});   
    });   
}

$.fn.mySlideUp = function (onend) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).stop(true,true)
           .css({"opacity": 1, "top":"-25px"}).show()
            .animate({ "opacity":0,"top":"-225px"}, function(){
                $(this).hide();
                if (onend) onend();
                });   
    });   
}
```

then you can check if there are any visible tooltips, use subsequent animation, else just show necessary tooltip

```
           if ($('.document_wrapper:visible').length>0) 
               $('.document_wrapper:visible').mySlideUp(function(){
                    $(''+div+'').mySlideDown();
                });
            else
              $(''+div+'').mySlideDown();
```

Have a look I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/dSCxJ/7/)